# React Native Push Notifications doesn't receive notification

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

I have a React Native app (testing on iOS) and am trying to incorporate Push notifications. I am using the following module:https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase-push-notifications.

I tried running example app code and am able to obtain 
 a (1) message token and (2) successfully obtain permissions from my device.

I am trying to send a test notification from Firebase and am using my device's token. However, nothing happens upon triggering a test notification. Any tips? I believe I followed the key upload instructions correctly (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Although I thought I had done this in the past, I did not have Remote notification enabled in background modes, nor did I have Push notifications checked in the `Signing & Capabilities` section of project setting on Xcode. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have uploaded pem/p8 file on firebase console at "Cloud Messaging" in  Project settings.  [Check this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/107mgWrC9qXhF5HBtrt66WXS3DPnQEPh8/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Yes, I have that uploaded. Does sending notifications from Firebase fail silently?